# problem with image in php

Tags: php, image

I want to show an image and wrote below codes

```
$path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\me\1.jpg";
$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image1);
```

But when I run it in Firefox it shows:

> The image
>   “http://127.0.0.1/me/Untitled%201.php”
>   cannot be displayed because it
>   contains errors.

What is problem?

**Edit:**

I deleted header function but it has this error:

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:
>   mpp\htdocs\me.jpg)
>   [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed
>   to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\me\Untitled 1.php on
>   line 136
>
> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\me\Untitled
>   1.php on line 138

after all works it shows some chars like this

```
    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ¸)"ÿÄ ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?ùþŠ( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š( Š
```

Comment: the problem was solved by removing <html> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, you forgot to escape the backslashes `\` in the file path. Either use escaped backslashes `\\` or - much better - forward slashes: `/`

```
   $path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/me/1.jpg";
```

To debug stuff like this, remove the `header()` line to see the image's source code to see the PHP error messages that are breaking it.

Comment: Was going to say that. On windows servers I usually use `c:\\folder\\folder2\\file.ext` single slashes don't work unless you use forward slashes or double backslashes. It's also clearly visible in your error, it states `C: xampp` instead of `C:\xampp`

Comment: @mehdi did you put the header back in after fixing the problem? Removing the header is meant for debugging purposes only. To see the image, you need the header.

Comment: **The image “http://127.0.0.1/me/Untitled%201.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.**

Comment: Strange. So there is no human-readable error message in the peculiar characters? If `1.jpg` indeed is a valid JPG file, I don't know what this is then.

Answer (score 1):

You image contains errors, what errors? Try temponary removing `header()` functions.

```
$path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\me\1.jpg";
$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
#header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image1);
```

Answer (score 1):

(C: mpp\htdocs\me.jpg)

As yor see this differs from

(C:\mpp\htdocs\me.jpg)

So your need change your code:

```
$path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/me/1.jpg";
$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image1);
```

Or like this:

```
$path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\me\1.jpg';
$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image1);
```

Also to debug:

1. Remove header.
2. Make echo ...

:

```
$path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\me\1.jpg'; <-- single quoted
echo $path;
$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); <-- commented
imagejpeg($image1);
```

Arsen

Comment: @mehdi that's the expected output.